# How do i populate an array from a txt file when i have to use file reader Java??

Tags: java, arrays, filereader

I have to populate an array with integers that are in a text file, i need the file reader to take an integer from each line and put into an array but it cant put duplicates in to the array aswell which is making it even more complex, and the duplicates, i have to write them to another text file eg:sorted.txt , i cant figure it out how to do all that im only in my first year i college. if someone could help would be gratefully appreciated. Thank you in advance

here is what i got so far in my Method

```
public static void readFromfile()throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
     reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
     String line = null;
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
    }
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
int[] array = lines.toArray();// i keep getting incopatible type error in this line
awell
```

for the last 6 days iv bein doing this and thats how far i got :(

Comment: each line in the text file contains 1 int?

Comment: the first mistake is the you try to convert a list of string to an int array: int[] array = lines.toArray();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> int[] array = lines.toArray();// i keep getting incopatible type error in this line
> ```

Of course you do, `List<String>#toArray` returns an `Object[]`, not an `int[]`. :-)

Ideally, you'd be able to do this by declaring your list as `List<int>` (or `List<long>` if the numbers will be really big). Unfortunately, at least in Java 6, you can't do that, you have to use `List<Integer>` / `List<Long>` instead. So that's your starting point.

Then *parse* the numbers from the strings (e.g., from `line`) as you go. [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) (or [`Long.parseLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)) can do the parsing for you. Their results are `int` and `long` respectively, but they'll get auto-boxed when added to the list.

Alternately, you might look at the [`Scanner` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), which is *"...A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions..."*

To get the final array of `int[]` (for instance) from the `List<Integer>` list is a bit of a pain. If you can use an `Integer[]` instead (and you mostly can, thanks to autoboxing / unboxing), that's easy: `Integer[] numbers = yourList.toArray(new Integer[yourList.size()]);`

If you really need an `int[]` instead, you'll have to write a loop to copy it, or use something like the [Apache Commons `toPrimitive` method](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Integer%5B%5D%29).

Answer (score 0):

Using the Scanner class will make things easier.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("file.txt"));

while (s.hasNextInt()) {
   numbers.add(s.nextInt());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a `List of Strings` and your trying to turn that into an `int array`.

As T.J. Crowder pointed out, BUT you cannot have a `List<int>` - you must use the wrapper class `Integer`.

So change your list to `List<Integer>`, and then it will be `lines.add(Integer.parseInt(line));`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Scanner class, it is easier than what you are doing.
The error is due to assigning object to integer type.